# Can I improve handwriting recognition in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, handwriting

When I convert a handwritten passage from ink to text I get decent, but not 100% correct recognition. With speech recognition you can teach the software to understand your voice better, is there a similar method for handwriting? Specifically in OneNote 2010/2013.

Comment: You could always used different OCR software.  Outside of that I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1):

There is a training that improves handwriting recognition overall in Windows.
There are 50 sentences and you have to train for each language used. However, you can save and transfer these "training files" :
[Transfer handwriting personalization to another Tablet PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Transfer-handwriting-personalization-to-another-Tablet-PC?d82ae840)

Yoga member at Surface Forums explains how to find it in Windows 8+ by going to ["the handwriting "training". It's in "control panel"/"Time, Language,Region"/"Add Language"/. Edit the Options of the installed language."](http://www.surfaceforums.net/threads/handwriting-recognition.4146/)

Comment: This is only a little better than a "just a link" answer. If you could copy/paste the instructions on how to get into the handwriting recognition training program, this answer would be much better.

Comment: I'll try to do that later today, though my system is in pt-br and windows 8.1. So, I don't know if it will help too much.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the control Panel Language options sections. Use the personalize handwriting training tool. Complete the 50 sentences. Works fantastic after that.